# Laravel schedule:run not executing scheduled commands

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

I'm not quite understanding how the laravel scheduling and `schedule:run` are working, at least it is not working the way I'd expect it to.

In app/Console/Kernel.php, a command is scheduled to run every five minutes:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('myscope:mycommand')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

In expectation of it being run when executing `php artisan schedule:run` in the console, I only get the `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` message.

Playing around with it, I found out that defining the schedule as `cron('*/2 * * * *')` leads to it being executed on every `schedule:run` call. Changing it to `cron('*/15 * * * *')` won't run anything, though, even after around 20 minutes.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or am I just using it the wrong way? In my understanding, `schedule:run` is basically the same command that is configured in the crontab, which is why I'm expecting it to also work by simply calling it in the terminal.

Comment: did you modify your crontab like this `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I'm talking about calling that one on the command line, locally, while developing/testing. It does not work there. The cron executes the same command AFAIK, so I'd say it won't work there, either. But yes, the crontab looks like this.